# Print CommandLine Flags using Unified JVM Logging

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

Running a Java program with OpenJDK 8, the following JVM flag

```
-Xloggc:/var/log/gc.log
```

causes the generated log file to include the following line

```
CommandLine flags: -XX:InitialHeapSize=263196800 -XX:MaxHeapSize=4211148800 -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:-UseLargePagesIndividualAllocation -XX:+UseParallelGC
```

thus providing the explicit and implicit JVM arguments of the running program.

Running a Java program with OpenJDK 17, thus using the Unified JVM Logging, I can't figure out how to print the explicit and implicit JVM arguments. I tried this option

```
-Xlog:all=trace
```

which, for the smallest Java program, produces 21k lines of logging, but a quick search of `-XX:` gives nothing. Also tried

```
-Xlog:arguments=trace
```

but the few output lines don't include what I need.

Here are the minimal steps to reproduce the issue, on Linux x64:

```
wget https://github.com/adoptium/temurin17-binaries/releases/download/jdk-17.0.4.1%2B1/OpenJDK17U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_17.0.4.1_1.tar.gz
tar xvf OpenJDK17U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_17.0.4.1_1.tar.gz
git clone https://github.com/jarirajari/helloworld.git
jdk-17.0.4.1+1/bin/java -Xlog:arguments=trace -XX:+UseG1GC -jar helloworld/helloworld.jar
```

The output is the following, and there's nothing about the JVM arguments I passed to the java executable:

```
[0.022s][trace][arguments] Memory size (original) 10485760 B (user defined: false)
[0.022s][trace][arguments] Memory size (adjusted) 10485760 B (modified: false)
[0.022s][trace][arguments] Memory size (adjustment) +0 B
[0.022s][trace][arguments] Global buffer size (original) 524288 B (user defined: false)
[0.022s][trace][arguments] Global buffer size (adjusted) 524288 B (modified: false)
[0.022s][trace][arguments] Global buffer size (adjustment) +0 B
[0.022s][trace][arguments] Thread local buffer size (original) 8192 B (user defined: false)
[0.022s][trace][arguments] Thread local buffer size (adjusted) 8192 B (modified: false)
[0.022s][trace][arguments] Thread local buffer size (adjustment) +0 B
[0.022s][trace][arguments] Number of global buffers (original) 20 (user defined: false)
[0.022s][trace][arguments] Number of global buffers (adjusted) 20 (modified: false)
[0.022s][trace][arguments] Number of global buffers (adjustment) +0
Hello world from HelloWorld.jar!
```

Any idea ?

Comment: `[0.003s][info][arguments] jvm_args: -Xlog:arguments=trace -XX:+UseG1GC`

Comment: @boneill I improved the question trying the arguments you suggested but nothing changed. Added also the minimal steps to reproduce the issue, with the latest Eclipse Temurin OpenJDK v17.

Comment: It looks like the jvm_args line is only available in Java 18 and above. https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8270801